# Loop through Query Results Printing Certain Record First

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a general programming question but for reference, I'm iterating through results from a Wordpress Query (WP_Query) of staff members. One of my records has a particular advanced custom field checkbox "manager". As I loop through and print results out, I want the one record with "manager" to be printed first then followed by the rest of the results. Problem is, this one record could appear at any place in the order.

What is the best way to iterate through the loop printing the particular checked record first followed by the remaining records?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the query via manager field DESC

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'manager',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This way you can get managers on the top

Comment: That was so simple and it worked. I had been incorrectly trying to use orderby =>"meta_value" for a set "meta_key".

Comment: Actually it didn't. It just sorted by alphabetically and the person happened to come first. =(

Comment: orderby must include the column in which you have that he/she is manager or not

Comment: also print your db table for more understanding